# add or subtract value from a field in a data bank with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

This is my primira posting here, since most already would like to thank everyone.

I am using codeigniter in my application, I need to do is the following I have in my database a field with name stock, this field is integer value, I need to do the following when I hold a sale he will have to decrease the amount of my selling this field in php would be something like this.

`$sql = mysql_query( sprintf( “UPDATE profile_posts SET cliks = cliks + 1 WHERE id = %d” , $id ) ) or die( mysql_error( ) );`

Is there some of codeigniter feature that I can do this or do I have to do a specific sql for this:

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Codeigniter to deal  with a MySQL database, you can simplify your code with **[Codeigniter Active Record Class](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update)** :

```
$data = array(
           'title' => $title,
           'name' => $name,
           'date' => $date
        );

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data); 

// Produces:
// UPDATE mytable 
// SET title = '{$title}', name = '{$name}', date = '{$date}'
// WHERE id = $id
```

...But I strongly recommend **[Datamapper ORM](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/update.html)**, which allows you to manipulate your database tables and entries as objects. The concept may seem a little strange if you' re only used to pure MySQL, but once you grasp it, it is a huge time saver, and you'll never have to manually write a full mySQL query again.

With Datamapper you can write your queries like this :

```
 $profile_post = new Profile_post(); // POINTS TO A MYSQL TABLE NAMED 'profile_posts'
 $profile_post->get_by_id($id); // GET THE PROFILE POST TO BE UPDATED
 $success = $profile_post->update('cliks', 'cliks+1');
```